# How to mark a string for translation?

Tags: c++, qt

I have some strings in cpp and i want to translate those strings.

```
m_stringText.append(qtTrId("abcId")); //Actual string : ABC
```

After using lupdate and lrelease command, the above string is not getting updated.
Also .ts and .qm files are getting updated. Only the updated string is not reflecting in cpp side.

What mistake i am doing here?
I am able to do translation for qml side properly, but its not working for cpp. Is there anything i am missing ??

Comment: Did you run lrelease tool with `-idbased` option?

Comment: I want qtTrId() only.

Comment: Yes i have added -idbased option

Comment: Does your program load the resulting qm file as a translator?

Comment: Yes it load the qm files too